# How do I identify which external routine is potentially internally used when executing some built-in function?

Tags: undocumented, librarylink

Wolfram's website declares that "a large fraction of Mathematica's numerical algorithms are based on original research at Wolfram Research" (cf. [So Many Original Wolfram Algorithms](https://www.wolfram.com/algorithmbase/)).  So, when I evaluate the discrete Fourier transform via `` System`Fourier `` (not `` Signal`SymbolicFourier `` or `` CUDALink`CUDAFourier ``), how do I identify if Mathematica makes use of certain original DFT methods pioneered by the Wolfram Research?
Well, I speculate that in the major computations (that is, excluding preprocessing and postprocessing), Mathematica essentially calls some *external* routine (rather than runs a Wolfram implementation). In the following directory:

```
System`Private`$DynamicLibraryPath\[LeftDoubleBracket]2\[RightDoubleBracket]
(*…\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\13.3\SystemFiles\Libraries\Windows-x86-64*)
```

I find something like "ipp*.dll" and "mkl*.dll". But since [Intel IPP and Intel MKL both provide optimized Fourier Transform functions](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/onemkl-ipp-choosing-an-fft.html), how to confirm which one is called in fact? (The documentation does not mention this point.)
Besides, I find a *third-party* library "flint-17.dll" in that path as well. And I read that Mathematica offers [faster](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/compare-mathematica/files/PolynomialFactoringMathematica13.2Maple2022.pdf) polynomial factorization operations. Now that "many algorithms in Mathematica are now found with Wolfram Research's unique automated algorithm discovery methods", can I fairly state that this improved performance is **chiefly** credited to Mathematica? Or is this simply contributed to the FLINT library instead? (Actually, [https://search.wolfram.com/?q=FLINT](https://search.wolfram.com/?query=FLINT) returns nothing about FLINT (at least) at present. How can the user know whether the pivot of a built-in functionality refers to (probably compiled) code developed by Wolfram Research or utilizes **third-party** subroutines (under valid license agreements)?)

Comment: Wolframs claim is true, historically, because the system can develop numerical aproximations, plots and interpolations with a few line of code and visible results in the GUI. But what today is Mathematica is probably 100% import from research from the worldwide community implementing their task on the platform. For a commercial project its of course essential to shield its product from to much insight by users. The more so, because mathematical theorems and algorithms have not yet been shielded by a Texan village jugde as personal property underlying copyright rules.

Comment: @RolandF Thanks. One of my worries is whether this will be a marketing skill and then lead to a one-sided propaganda. Well, I am not in a position to query Wolfram Mathematica; one should **not** cut down the tree that gives one shade. I except that this question is not unreasonable inasmuch as [Wolfram tech is mostly open](https://blog.wolfram.com/2021/11/30/six-reasons-why-the-wolfram-language-is-like-open-source/).